# Frequency demodulation circuit

Tags: frequency, communication, modulation, frequency-modulation, demodulation

This is how I designed the frequency modulation circuit, but I cannot perform the demodulation process. It can be done with a PLL but I couldn't install it. How can I demodulate?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried asking on the help site for the specific tool you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Your simulator has the model of (ancient) ICL8038 analog function generator IC and the model seemingly works so that you can get the FM output.

FM demodulators generally must be designed for a certain center frequency and deviation. Wide band detector which adapts to the center frequency is possible, but you have more options, even some which could be built with 1930's parts, if the frequency and the max. deviation are fixed.

Get some articles which tell the different FM demodulation ideas. Here's one:
https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/radio/modulation/fm-frequency-demodulation-detection-discrimination.php

One popular idea in radio receivers is to adjust automatically the voltage level of the FM signal good for the demodulators. The levelling also clips all kinds of random spikes to reduce  audible noises caused by electric motors and other noisy devices.

When the voltage level of the FM signal  is well controlled numerous demodulating principles work. You wanted PLL. Then you must design a PLL which locks to the center frequency of the input signal. Modulation makes the frequency of the input signal swing and that essentially can be seen as diminishing or increasing phase difference between the locked PLL oscillator output and the input signal. I skip the math details of it, but the phase detector output as low-pass filtered is the demodulated signal.

Speaking exactly it's the demodulated signal as low-pass filtered with a 1st order filter, but that harm is precompensated already in radio transmitters by performing a high frequency boost which is called "pre-emphasis". It can be shown undeniably that high frequency pre-emphasis in modulation and compensating it by low pass filtering in receivers gives a substantial S/N ratio boost.

It's your job to build the PLL which locks to the center frequency of the input signal and design its loop filtering so that the phase detector output (as low-pass filtered) is a good demodulation result with your deviation. If you have the model of ICL8038 you surely have also some PLL ICs from the last quarter of 1900's. Manufacturer's application notes give the needed circuits and formulas. Of course, they are useful only, if you bother to study the ideas behind them so well that you can understand the application notes.

BTW. Your example simulation plot seems to have quite large deviation and high baseband signal frequency when compared to the carrier frequency. You may need to reduce them to keep the phase difference between the center frequency oscillator output and input signal in the unambiguously detectable range.